# How do I write a List<String> into a .csv file as a single column?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

Right now I have a simple application where I have a C# object that has a `List<String>` as part of its attributes. It is supposed to store a list of strings alongside the other attributes and output it as a .csv file with headers.

After creating the object and outputting it as a .csv file, the column containing the list is not in the output and I don't know how to exactly handle it or converting it to a .csv format.

My intended output is:

```
Name,ID,Date,Number,FilePaths,Remarks
Value1, Value2, Value3, Value 4,List here,Value6
```

The output .csv file will then be serialized into JSON and be deserialized in another component where it is going to read the values and eventually be put into a database.

The class (POCO):

```
class Object 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public long Number { get; set; }
   public List<String> FilePaths { get; set; }
   public string Messages {get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I instantiate the object from the data collected from inputs:

```
List<String> paths = new List<String>();

foreach(var file in files)
{
   paths.Add(file.FullName);
}

List<Object> newObject = new List<Object> {
new Object { Name = value1, ID = value2, Date = value3, Number = value4, FilePaths = paths, Messages = value6 };

using(var writer = new CsvWriter(outputStream))
{
   writer.WriteRecords(newObject);
}
```

However the output seems to be:

```
Name,ID,Date,Number,Remarks
value1,value2,value3,value4,value6
```

It seems to have skipped the list.

EDIT:

To elaborate further, the FilePaths are actually a list of strings that contain the directory paths of files the user has uploaded to the program. What I plan to do is to have the list of file paths retrieved from `List<FileInfo> files` by calling a for loop and storing their paths into an organized fashion. This is because one user has the ability to upload multiple files as according to the requirements.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that? It's my first time using CsvHelper as a way to read/write .csvs.

Comment: Oh! I apologize, `Header1` was just the example I thought of. The actual csv's headers are named as what it seems to be on the output.

Comment: Did @AD8's suggestion work?

Comment: @AD8's suggestion was my initial idea too, but the requirements did state that the program is supposed to output a .csv that would be the input to a json serializer, which then goes through a deserializer and finally be put into a database. I'm supposed to keep the file paths in an array/list<string> and I'm having a hard time figuring out the solution.

Comment: Are you sure the output has `Remarks`? I am pretty sure it would be `Messages`. Also, `Name`, `ID` and so on are called "Properties" not "Attributes". Attributes in c# are something totally different. ADT's answer should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CsvHelper skips over `Enumerable` properties unless you give it more information on how it should handle them.  This would be one way to output your CSV file by separating each FilePath value with a comma.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var paths = new List<string> { "path1", "path2", "path3" };

    List<Object> newObject = new List<Object> {
        new Object
        {
            Name = "NameValue",
            ID = "IdValue",
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Number = 12345,
            FilePaths = paths,
            Messages = "MessagesValue"
        }
    };

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(outputStream))
    {
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new ObjectMap());
        csv.WriteRecords(newObject);
    }
}

public class ObjectMap : ClassMap<Object>
{
    public ObjectMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map(m => m.FilePaths).TypeConverter<ListStringConverter>();
    }
}

private class ListStringConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var returnValue = string.Empty;

        var list = (List<string>)value;

        if (list != null)
        {
            returnValue = string.Join(",", list);
        }        

        return base.ConvertToString(returnValue, row, memberMapData);
    }

    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var list = text.Split(',').ToList();

        return list;
    }
}

public class Object
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }
    public List<String> FilePaths { get; set; }
    public string Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much David, now I understand how it works and this solution worked. I had trouble understanding how it works initially because I've only worked with types like `int` `string` and stuff. Really is interesting to see how to make it work with `Enumerable` collections!

Answer (score 1):

Declare FilePaths as string. 
Convert List as the string you want and 
And then write to csv file.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, so basically I'll have to convert the class attribute as

   `public String FilePaths { get; set; }` instead?

Comment: That's one way to go. But once you are using Json, why do you need to write csv ? Why don't you convert the class to Json directly?

Comment: It's part of the specifications for the homework, I was stuck on this part for a rather long time.

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing your list of object as the following:

```
List<Object> newObject = new List<Object> {
            new Object {
                  Name = value1,
                  ID = value2,
                  Date = value3,
                  Number = value4,
                  FilePaths = paths.Any() ? $"\"{string.Join(",", paths.ToList())}\"" : null;,
                  Messages = value6
            }
      };
```

Comment: I suspect the `Any` check is not necessary.

Comment: @mjwills, you may be right, but I didn't have setup to test this and wanted to make sure it doesn't break. Hence why I left that in. Thanks for pointing that out.